# Как в Deploy конфигурации создать зависимость артефакта? И написать правило для артефактов? Спасибо вам?

Tags: развертывание, teamcity

У меня есть два Bulid Confurations:

1. Build.
2. Deploy.

В *Build* конфигурации указал артефакты (http://prntscr.com/enws67). В *Deploy* конфигурации папка dist берется и перемещается на сервер с помощью rsync (сценарий bash уже написан: http://prntscr.com/enwtzr).

(До этого я создавал одну Билд Конфигурацию в которой был прописан шаг для деплоя и запуском скрипта в командной строке: `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe /cygdrive /c /cygwin64 /Home /Team /Startsync.bash`)

Идея заключается в том, что правила задаются на конфигурации, которая генерирует артефакты (*Build*) и конфигурацию, которая их потребляет (*Deploy*). Таким образом, одна конфигурация может передавать другой конфигурации файлы.

Как в *Deploy* конфигурации создать зависимость артефакта? И написать правило для артефактов? Спасибо вам !

Comment: как то сложным путем вы пошли. Edit Configuration Settings  -> Dependencies -> Add new artifact dependency

Comment: Идея в том чтобы  разделить Конфигурации для Билда и Деплоя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build конфигурация билдит артефакты, в конце ты их выкачиваешь и они отображаются в artifacts

2) в Deploy кон-ии переходим в `Edit Configuration Settings` -> `Dependencies` -> `Add new artifact dependency`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Depend on:   указываем Build конфигурацию

Artifacts rules: * пишем правила

```
+: one => . 
-: second
```

`+:` говорит включить папку one для скачивания в папку `checkout.directory/`

`-:` - исключает папку second

знак `=>` ссылается на `checkout.directory`

более подробно по [ссылке](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Artifact+Dependencies)